# bootstrap modal not rounded but square

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm using adminlte for asp.net webform project. In the master page I've imported all js and css. My problem is the bootstrap modal is not a rounded shape but square. Please see below image. Why is that? Please help, thanks!

[image: square side modal]

```
//Master Page
   <!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="adminlte/plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI 1.11.4 -->
<script src="adminlte/plugins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link href="adminlte/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="adminlte/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- DataTables -->
 <link href="Scripts/DataTables-1.10.7/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

//aspx file (not aspx master page)
    function openModal() {
    enableDataTable();
    $('#mBarbers').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: I use google chrome.

Comment: What you have done? Just show us the code.

Comment: Create: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I'm working on asp.net, js fiddle doesn't have that platform. Besides, I attached the screen shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the code for your actual output it's hard to tell. It's likely a style somewhere overriding the border radius of the `.modal-content` class. To find out what's going on, follow these steps to trace the style.

Since you say you are using Chrome, go into Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-I or Menu - More Tools - Developer Tools).

Open up your pretty Bootstrap modal.

Go to the Elements tab. Choose the Element Picker (a tool in the top right of the dev toolbar that looks like a mouse pointer)

Hover over your modal and it should highlight. Click it and it will be highlighted in the elements panel. You should also have a Styles tab which will list the styles assosciated with that element.

You may have to dig around a bit now, but once you find the 'modal-content' element this should have a css rule in it for `border-radius`. Here's an example from one of my projects.

```
.modal-content{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px; /*<!-- HERE I AM!---*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    outline: none;
}
```

The problem could be that your version of the bootstrap css does not have the border-radius part in it. If you want it, you can just add it in or add in a stylesheet at a higher level that will apply it, something like 'custom.css' with a rule in that just adds border-radius to the modal-content class. That way you don't need to overwrite/change the 3rd party css.

Hopefully that helps to at least figure out the problem, as said earlier, without the relevant snippets of code (we don't need the ASP, just the output html/css) this is mostly guessing.

Answer (score 4):

I just found a work around that is not horrible, though I'd almost expect this to be in bootstrap.

```
.modal-content {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and noticed that if I set the following css style, the background color I chose, went over the corners. When I removed this css background color, I saw the rounded edges again:

```
.modal-body, .modal-header, .modal-footer {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: are you using adminLTE template?